# Did I break Encapsulation?

Tags: c#, oop, events, delegates

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();
        b.Run();
        Console.Read();
    }
}

class A
{
    public event Action onChanged;

    public void Raise()
    {
        if (onChanged != null)
            onChanged();
    }
}

class B
{
    public void Run()
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.onChanged += a_onChanged;
        a.Raise();
    }

    private void a_onChanged()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wow! Invoked");
    }       

}
```

I am not able to figure out the Valid points which can justify that I broke encapsulation or may be otherwise. As per my understanding I am breaking encapsulation as a private method is getting called from another class, Is this enough for justifying that I broke on the laws of OOP. Need to gather some more inner concepts and descrption for the code above.

Comment: FYI: Your `event Action onChanged` should be called `Changed`. The `OnXxx` is used for virtual methods that then raise the `Xxx` events.

Comment: Nothing is broken. You've wraped private method in a delegate class, which has public `Invoke` method. Your event calls public `Invoke` method of delegate, which calls method, which was passed to delegate at initialization time.

Comment: "Oh, sorry... Did I break your encapsulation?" - _(read in Samuel L. Jackson voice)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really depends on why do you have a `Raise` method in class A.

If it there solely for enabling the access to a private member, then the answer would be: yes, your encapsulation has been compromised.
The `onChanged` event should occur when something has changed and not when some external class decides it should.

However, if this is only a simple snapshot for making a point, and the `Raise` event is a method that is triggering the event as a side effect to an action taken (something like changing text in a `Textbox` and then triggering `onTextChanged`) than your encapsulation is still in tact.

**Note:**

> I am breaking encapsulation as a private method is getting called
>   from another class

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29#General_definition):

> Encapsulation is used to hide the values or state of a structured data
>   object inside a class, preventing unauthorized parties' direct access
>   to them. Publicly accessible methods are generally provided in the
>   class (so-called getters and setters) to access the values, and other
>   client classes call these methods to retrieve and modify the values
>   within the object.

It is OK for the private method to be called from a public one. How else would it be called? It is up to you, the programmer, to get your methods logic straight and make sure that they call the appropriate methods.

Comment: +1 for `If it there solely for enabling the access to a private member, then the answer would be: yes, your encapsulation has been compromised`. Encapsulation is used to make sure that the object itself can control that it's behavior and state is valid. Allowing external parties to trigger state removes that control and can therefore make an object behave with undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Avi - Not able to understand what are you tryiny to say here- "However, if this is only a simple snapshot for making a point, and the Raise event is a method that is triggering the event as a side effect to an action taken (something like changing text in a Textbox and then triggering onTextChanged) than your encapsulation is still in tact."

Comment: @Bose_geek I mean that if this is not your actual code that raises the event, and the real code is more like the example of `TextChanged`,   then your encapsulation is still in tact. If this is still not clear, let me know and I will post a demonstration.

Comment: @Avi - I got your point. I would be great if you can demostrate as well(just get crystal clear picture) that can show how in that case encapsulation remains intact.

Comment: @Bose_geek I posted a [sample code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tcwaAH). if any further clarification is required, please live a comment...

Comment: @Bose_geek If any of the answered helped you, please consider to mark an answer as Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't break encapulation on class B, since instances of B only modify themselves, but yes, you broke encapsulation on class A.  Anything that has a reference to an instance of A can raise the onChanged event.

Comment: Events can only be subscribed to, there is no "modification" as such. Events are designed to work this way, and be publicly accessible if needed. I would consider encapsulation on an event to be broken only when an external class can raise the event. Which happens to be true in this case, irrespective of whether the `onChanged` field can be "modified"

Answer (score 0):

No, you did not break encapsulation and *a private method is getting called from another class* is not true in this case. Class `B` creates it's own `A` and calls it's `Raise` method which raises an `onChanged` event.
You are registering to this event **from** `B` therefore it's completely fine.